# How to fetch Images from server Using API and push in Array

Tags: angular

I want to fetch images from my server using API and then I want to push in array so that I can show this images in loop or as slideshow, I have page named common service where I  have mentioned image API url. now I just want to know how to get it in my component.ts and want to push in array.
I am Using Angular 4

I have tried to create a function in .ts to get images  but not working.

common.service.ts

```
this.surveyImageUrl = this.authService.website_url + '/SurveyImages/';
```

here i tried to get images in ts.file

```
optionimage: any[] = [{}];
surveyImageUrl = function () {
    debugger;
    this.commonService.surveyImageUrl().subscribe(data => {
        if (data.success) {
            data.survey.array.forEach(element => {
                var obj = {
                    is_optionimages: true,
                    surveyImage: element.surveyImage,
                }
                this.optionimage.push(element);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Just want to get images then want to push in array and want to display in HTML page as loop.

Comment: How are you returning your images to the Angular client 'surveyImage'? Are returning the image path in your server?

Comment: Yes, I have image path in common.service page

Comment: Please have  have look on common service page

Comment: Are you getting errors from the http calls?

Comment: Actually, Before I was getting this image in direct in html page from common service page but  here I want to show thing image in slideshow that's why first I need push these images in array, then I can show as Slideshow

Comment: No, I am not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    optionimage: any[] = [];
    surveyImageUrl = function () {
    debugger;
    this.commonService.surveyImageUrl().subscribe(data => {

      if (data.success) {
        data.survey.array.forEach(element => {
          var obj = {
            is_optionimages: true,
            surveyImage: element.surveyImage,

          }
          this.optionimage.push(obj);
        });

      }

    });
  }
```

**Then you can bind your image urls to View as below.**

```
<div *ngFor="let image of optionimage">
<img [src] = "image.surveyImage"/>
</div>
```

Comment: but what about the  HTML

Comment: If I write something like this then its not working
<img [src] = "optionimage"/>

Comment: I wan  achieve in this format 
  <ngx-slides [slideImages]="slideImages" [config]="config"></ngx-slides>

Comment: after calling `surveyImageUrl()` `try console.log` on response data and check whether is there image urls

Comment: I have  tried this way
this.commonService.getOptionimage().subscribe(data => {
      if (data.success){
        this.surveyImage = data;
        console.log(data);
              }
    })

Comment: but I am nothing getting in console